# Calculate one-tailed critical point from a probability distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would like to calculate the numerical value of $\xi\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$$$P(|U|<\xi)=0.95$$
where $U$ is standard-normal distributed.

How may I do that in Mathematica?

Comment: `Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], .95]` might be what you want?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `Quantile[NormalDistribution[0,1],.975]`

Comment: @ssch Right you are, I was making a mental reversal somewhere (probably in my mind).

Comment: Dear Kasper, the community has seriously downvoted you on this question because of the way it was asked and the fact that this was something you could have easily looked up in the *Mathematica* documentation. I have edited your question to be a bit less demanding in tone, and would encourange you to phrase your future questions on Mathematica.SE in a similar way, and to *show what you tried*. That said, welcome to Mathematica.SE and I hope that you find the site useful in future.

Comment: @Verbeia Dear Verbeia, the OP had been visiting SE sites for at least two months now. S/he should know (if s/he cares about it) that a demanding tone isn't welcomed. That said, I hope your efforts aren't in vain

Comment: @Verbeia Sorry for the demanding tone, it wasn´t meant to be demanding. I copied the question word by word out of my book, I should have edited a little bit. 
Believe it or not, but we have been searching for the answer in the documentation for a long time, when we almost reached the deadline, I just copied it here (in a hurry), hoping that this community could help us out, luckily you guys did. Thank you for that !

Comment: @Kasper But then why are you posting homework to a site that is not meant for such?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Solve[Probability[Abs[u] < \[Xi], u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]] == 95/100, \[Xi]]
```

> {{[Xi] -> Sqrt[2] InverseErf[19/20]}

```
Sqrt[2] InverseErf[19/20]// N
```

> 1.959963985

Comment: Including the lower bound gives: `Sqrt[2] InverseErf[19/20]`

Comment: Shouldn't I include Abs[u], like this:
    Solve[Probability[Abs[u] < \[Xi], 
    u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]] == 95/100, \[Xi]] // N

Comment: @Kasper Yes, missed the Abs in the question.

Answer (score 6):

```
 dist = TransformedDistribution[(Abs[u]), u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]];
 Quantile[dist .95]
 (* 1.95996 *)
```

or

```
InverseCDF[dist .95]
(* 1.95996 *)
```

or

```
Quantile[NormalDistribution[], .975] 
(*  1.95996  *)
```

or

```
InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], .975]
(*  1.95996  *)
```